# How to put React Native code with Spring Boot backend into source control?

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, version-control, project-structure

I'm developing a React Native app with Spring Boot backend. I've put the backend to github. Now I'm connecting to backend in React native part. Should I initialize a new repo or make folders like server and client for this?

Comment: It's better to create a new repo, if it was a react project then I would recommend putting it with spring. as React Native has no relation with spring it will just vai reat api

Answer (score 0):

I would use the same repo. Separate parts of the stack in different folders.
Ask yourself this, if you want to add a new page, are both front end and back end affected? Probably. When this happens, 1 repo is so much easier to handle. You can make sure 1 commit adds front end l and back end code. And that you don't have to coordinate repos to make sure you deploy the correct version of front end and back end. You just deploy the repo.